# replace all comma by dot in file with snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to replace all the comma by a dot in a csv file using snowflake ?
I'm using the replace in the `copy into` but this lead to write a lot of row coding and i would like to found a process which replace directly all the comma.

is it possible to make a loop on each column of the csv file and replace the comma like this ?

```
DECLARE ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @ColNames = (@ColNames +)
    CASE
        WHEN c.DATA_TYPE IN ('DECIMAL') THEN REPLACE(c.DATA_VALUE, ',','.')
        ELSE c.DATA_VALUE
    END
```

i used this code for the moment but it does'nt work

```
copy into PUBLIC.VENTE from (select replace(c.*,',','.') from @test_database/file.csv c);
```

Thanks in advance for you help,

Comment: Please add more details to your question, including what a "file" means here.

Comment: Are you referring to unloading data using COPY INTO <location>?

Comment: yes, data is in a stage and i want to import them in table snowflake but the commas in the numerics fields is not accepted and so i use the replace in the copy into but sometimes i've one hundred of columns and i don't want to write too coding lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do replace(c.*,',','.') across ALL columns, it has to be on column by column, like below:

```
replace(c.$1, ',', '.'), replace(c.$2, ',', '.') ...
```

Alternatively, you can create a SP to build the list of columns for you if the column number is large and you need to use it often.